# Post the selected option from html “select” to other field

Tags: javascript, html, select

I'm not very good at scripting, sorry for that :)

I have html/php project. I found javascript that makes my project amazing :) but... The script job is when user enter some text in "input" filed that text is replacing/posting to another field in DIV that contains the same name like input. That works great.

```
<LABEL FOR='profile_name'>Profile name:</LABEL>
<INPUT TYPE='text' ID='$id' NAME='profile_name' CLASS='variable'></INPUT>
```

But I add "select" field with some options - to do the same thing like input - and the javascripts looks like working fine, when I chose some option, BUT only when I press "TAB" button, or when I press "Enter" button on that select the text is poulating on DIV field.
And this is my problem :( The "input" field when user is entering something the script online "live" is replacing DIV, but "select" - NO :(

Please help, thanks !
This is my problem :(

FULL Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/tubeto/wamc9b7u/2/

SELECT not working:

```
<LABEL FOR='PBH'>value:</LABEL></TD>
<SELECT TYPE='text' ID='$id' NAME='PBH' CLASS='variable'>
<OPTION selected>[PHB]</OPTION>
<OPTION value='be'>0</a></OPTION>
<OPTION value='af2'>2</OPTION>
<OPTION value='af4'>4</OPTION>
<OPTION value='ef'>5</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript too?

Comment: I'm using the code from this site:
http://www.hatchconfigs.com/templates/view/test-5/

But unfortunately, I clicked "Download template" and I dont know what is the script for me, because there is huge scirpt lines :(

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Can you please past `<select>` tag and its `<script>` which is working on pressing enter.

Comment: Please review [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understant you question correctly, but I'll give it a go.
You would like to have the `<input>` and `<select>` values duplicated in a `<div>` element, right?

Your problem seem to be with the `<select>` element. Maybe that's because the `<select>` is more complex than the `<input>`.

The `<input>` element has a value, but the `<select>` element has options inside and you have to get the value of the selected `<option>` element:

```
select.addEventListener('input', function() {
    selectOutput.innerHTML = select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
});
```

Here is a minimal working example in my understanding (please take note of it when asking questions):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  var select = document.getElementById('select');
  var labelOutput = document.getElementById('labelOutput');
  var selectOutput = document.getElementById('selectOutput');

  input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    labelOutput.innerHTML = input.value;
  });

  select.addEventListener('input', function() {
    selectOutput.innerHTML = select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  });
}
```

```html
<label for="profile_name">Profile name:</label>
<input type="text" id="input" name="profile_name">

<label for="PBH">value:</label>
<select id="select" name="PBH">
  <option selected="">[PHB]</option>
  <option value="be">0</option>
  <option value="af2">2</option>
  <option value="af4">4</option>
  <option value="ef">5</option>
</select>

<br>

<div>
  <span id="labelOutput"></span>
  <br>
  <span id="selectOutput"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: YES this is exacly what I need! :) :) I have problem that I'm explaining as Answer to post some code.

Comment: YES this is exacly what I need! :) :) But, I can't have skills to implement this solution on the scipt that I have :(, can you please help :( Also CLASS='variable' is importamnt, because when I delete this class - scipt stops working..

Comment: You have to understand that posting large and complex code won't help you get an answer.  You have to simplify it until you get to a minimal example that shows you problem. Even if you don't understand the code you've copied from various sources you can modify it in order to have a better understanding of how it works.

Comment: You can take my answer and build back on it, adding one thing at a time and see if you get sa same result as before. the `class` property has no effect on the functionality

Comment: I believe you're generating this code from PHP, it would be best to have a local html page running and after to implement the generation in PHP.